# Требуют ли обособления слова "максимум", "минимум"?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

**Это дело(,) максимум(,) одного дня.**

Выделяются ли слова "максимум" и "минимум" знаками препинания в таких довольно распространенных оборотах?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **«Как минимум».** Если в значении «самое меньшее», то без запятых. Например: «Как минимум вымою посуду»; «Он допустил как минимум десяток
>   ошибок».
>
> НО! Если в значении сравнения с чем-либо, эмоциональной оценки, то с
>   запятой. Например: «Как минимум, такой подход предполагает контроль»,
>   «Для этого нужно, как минимум, разбираться в политике».

То же с максимумом (в значении «самое большее»).

В Вашем примере запятые не нужны.

***Это дело максимум одного дня.***

Грамота.ру:

[**КАК МИНИМУМ, наречие**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_325)

> Не требует постановки знаков препинания.
>
> *Выводов отсюда проистекало **как минимум** два.* Б. Акунин, Внеклассное чтение. *Всё зависит от условий хранения... Трое суток
>   **как минимум**, если не четверо.* В. Богомолов, Момент истины. *Чтобы восстановить хозяйство, разрушенное войной, надо сначала его
>   разрушить, а для этого нужна гражданская или хоть какая-нибудь война,
>   нужно **как минимум** двенадцать фронтов…* В. Ерофеев, Москва-Петушки.
>
> @ Допускается пунктуационное выделение слов «как минимум» (как
>   содержащих уточнение), если в устной речи они сопровождаются
>   интонационной паузой.

Answer (score 2):

Это дело **максимум** одного дня.

1) Слова "максимум и минимум" **являются наречиями и не обособляются**, например: Приезжая сюда **максимум** два-три раза в год, вы по-прежнему считаете Мариинский своим театром? Сейчас эти нормы реализованы на сорок процентов **максимум**.

"Максимум и минимум" **могут относиться к обособленным оборотам или однородным членам:** Каждый знал, что через час, **максимум полтора,** он откроет дверь своей квартиры, где его уже ждут. А. Михайлов, Капкан для одинокого волка.Да кто он, этот Алехин?! Какой-нибудь выдвиженец – наверняка из деревни! – с пятью, **максимум семью** классами образования... В. Богомолов, Момент истины.

2) **Обороты "как минимум, как максимум" в большинстве случаев также не обособляются**, то есть входят в основное сообщение. Это означает, что автор не придает им уточняющего значения и строит структуру предложения таким образом, чтобы интонационно оборот вписывался в предложение, не требовал обособления.

Поэтому интересно обратить внимание на те случаи, **когда он обособляется.** При желании выделить оборот (подчеркнуть его значимость или придать значение уточнения) для него подбирается удобная позиция в структуре предложения (как правило, это начало или конец предложения, явная структурная несочетаемость с последующей частью текста и т.д.).

Примеры

**Как минимум,** можно насчитать два различных направления продвижения на рекламодателя и на потенциальных читателей. Десять минут, **как минимум**, потеряла от урока.  К обеду сорок ― сорок два набежит, как минимум. А тема такая выбрана сразу по нескольким причинам. **Как минимум** — это вынужденные обстоятельства.  Это свидетельствует, **как минимум**, о непоследовательности Елены Борисовны, но это ― **как минимум**.

Или, **как минимум**, за неосторожные публичные высказывания (Сергей Довлатов).